# Avg in sql adds zeros after the number

Tags: mysql

when i use AVG in sql it gets 2.7500 but i only want it to get the first 2 numbers 2.7/5 on the average rating

```
    $ratesavg =  "SELECT AVG(round(vote_num,1)) AS myAvg FROM post_votes WHERE post_id=$post_id GROUP BY post_id";
$avgrows = mysqli_query($conn, $ratesavg);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($avgrows)) {
  print_r($row);
  $a = $row['myAvg'];
  echo $a;
}
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE(your calculation here,1)` this will not round up ie. 2.76 --> 2.7.If you want round then use `ROUND(your calculation here,1)` ie. 2.76 --> 2.8

Comment: where should i add it exactly

Comment: i have 5 stars wish one do you recomand

Comment: do it. do it. do it. you can do it!

Comment: You should add it where you are `SELECT`ing.If not sure please post your query /code

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how it works

```
$ratesavg =  "SELECT round(AVG(vote_num), 1) AS myAvg FROM post_votes WHERE post_id=$post_id GROUP BY post_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the number as a string or convert it to a decimal/numeric:

```
select cast(avg(x) as numeric(4, 1))
```